# Custom CSS Class Not Being Applied

Tags: css, html

I have some custom CSS being applied to a list of posts.
The site is [here](http://mielleorganics.com/testimonials-test/)
If you are to check the css classes of the posts, you'll see that the last two css classes are `.floats` and `.colThree`.

`.colThree` is applying just fine and everything is great there. `.floats` will not apply and I can't figure it out. I thought maybe it was a bad CSS class name but I've changed it a couple of times.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What happens if you move `.colThree` above `.floats` in your css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the comments in your CSS file.

CSS doesn't mark comments the same way HTML does. You have your CSS comments formatted like this:

`<!-- commented text goes here -->`

...which is the right way to do it in HTML. In CSS, however, you'll want to wrap your comments like this:

`/* commented text goes here */`

You have two comments near the bottom of your main.css file (lines 1687 and 1690). I tested the page with those comments both reformatted and removed from the CSS file, and confirmed the .float styling was applied in both cases.

Comment: Oh. My. Goodness. Of course that's it. I can't believe I did that. Thank you so much.

Comment: It happens to us all! Sometimes the only thing you need is a fresh pair of eyes. :)